# How to route the Bluetooth audio A2DP into the audio device MediaStream ? (from electron app)

Tags: audio, web-applications, bluetooth, electron, web-bluetooth

I have an app that runs locally on a Debian Linux system.
The app is made with Electron and runs on Chromium.

From this app, I have access to many things, including files, locally installed programs.

At this point I use the app to make the bluetooth discovery with the web-bluetooth API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Bluetooth_API

I also have a local external audio card.
I can see the devices using the mediaDevices interface https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices

**Does someone know How to route the Bluetooth audio A2DP into the audio device MediaStream ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web Bluetooth supports [GATT](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/generic-attributes-overview) aka "Bluetooth Low Energy" aka "Bluetooth Smart".  A2DP is a legacy profile not supported in Web Bluetooth.

Comment: But Audio is transported through A2DP no? So do you mean web Bluetooth does just not support full Bluetooth just BLE and therefore no audio?

Comment: Thank you @VincentScheib at this point i guess I'll have to look into controlling external tools like commands to pulse audio directly.

Comment: Yes, that's the current state of things.